# Three.js: Using DeviceOrientationControls with a different base direction

Tags: three.js, quaternions

I'm using device orientation controls but need some additional functionality that I'm having difficulty with.

I want a user to be able to "lock" the camera, which prevents the camera orientation from changing. When the unlock it, I want the view to now rotate the camera from where they locked it, ie. i don't want the camera to "jump" to another orientation, even though their phone's orientation has changed while the view was locked.

Here's the code for for the modified version of DeviceOrientaionControls.js : https://gist.github.com/BruOp/a3fb2f0854357eb1182671cafd3fae89

The crucial parts are in `update`, `disconnect` and `reconnect`.

I'm bascially taking the orientation (call it `lockedRot`) that the user sees when they "lock", and then taking the orientation of the device when it's "unlocked" (`unlockedRot`). I then find the quaternion `deviceToPercieved` such that:

`deviceToPercieved * unlockedRot = lockedRot`

But it's not really working. Sometimes, the camera will only jump a little bit when being unlocked, but other times it fails to maintain the "locked" orientation entirely on unlock.

Am I taking the wrong approach here or am I missing something more fundamental?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem! It was just the order of multiplication when calculating the `deviceToPerceived` quaternion. It was:

```
this.deviceToPercieved.multiplyQuaternions(
  this.unlockedRot.clone().conjugate(),
  this.lockedRot
).normalize();
```

But it should actually be:

```
this.deviceToPercieved.multiplyQuaternions(
  this.lockedRot,
  this.unlockedRot.clone().conjugate()
);
```

Notice the change in the order of multiplication and the dropping of the `normalized()` call.

It works properly now!